# How difficult is it to build a basic transmitter and receiver

Tags: receiver, transmitter

Preferably something that could transmit LED lights, like patterns. After that I'd like to advance to audio and video. But for the basic radio transmitting and receiving how difficult of a job would that be? and what tools and parts would I need? I've worked on a off with electronics for about a year so I know about capacitors, resistors, transistors,transformers, arduinos, basic C and Python Programming. I think I could do this job but could use some guidance and information.

Comment: “How difficult” is a bit — subjective, and “what parts do I need” is best answered with a schematic in hand. May I suggest that you revise your question to something a little more definitively answerable, such as turning the first part into "what type of transmitter and receiver would I use to transmit a pattern of LED lights, and is there something simpler than that?"

Comment: Also, what distance are we talking about?

Comment: Please try some basic research before asking such a broad question (which is also nearly a duplicate of [your other question](http://ham.stackexchange.com/q/2419/218)).

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in RF experimentation and you prefer to work in a virtual environment, try GNURadio.  It runs in linux, and has the basic virtual components to build a variety of RF systems, including basic FM/AM transceivers.  There are many online tutorials to get you started with the basics, and you don't need a lab or any parts.  You just need a laptop and some time.  When you want to implement your designs in reality, look at getting a cheap SDR (Software defined radio).  They typically plug into the USB port of your computer, and can be purposed for almost anything (within the limitations of the SDR itself, of course!)

Comment: Also note that for GNU Radio, a lot of interfacing blocks to software defined radio peripherals exist, so you can bring your prototype to the real world ether by just replacing a block in a flow graph :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at "Experimental Methods in RF Design" from the ARRL, that will get you started in how to design and build radios.

A recent copy of the [ARRL](http://www.arrl.org) Handbook is also a must.